In finite fields of large characteristics,what does prevent shrinking the field size down to their larger order in order to solve discrete logarithms?
In the recent years, several algorithms were proposed to leverage elliptic curves for lowering the degree of a finite field and thus allow to solve discrete logarithm modulo their largest suborder/subgroup instead of the original far larger finite field. https://arxiv.org/pdf/2206.10327 in part conduct a survey about those methods. Especially since I don’t see why a large characteristics would be prone to fall in the trap cases being listed by the paper.
I do get the whole small characteristics algorithms complexity makes those papers unsuitable for computing discrete logarithms in finite fields of large characteristics, but what does prevent applying the descent/degree shrinking part to large characteristics ?

Please also note that I only understand how a suitable elliptic curve is generated but not how finite field elements are then mapped.

The question is of crypto interest, but of mathematical nature. It would thus also be on-topic on math-se, with a larger potential audience. I don't know which is best. I can migrate if you want. Update: there is also mathoverflow where the mathematical level is higher, perhaps too high given the nature of the question.

@fgrieu I would also say for mathoverflow that such algorithm are unfortunately (unless I m wrong) only implemented in labs (no public release) which means their descriptions only lies in scientific papers which in turns means the question is about scientific maths. The lack of implementation is a key to why I partially fails to understand how they work.

@fgrieu what happenned about migration?

I tried migration to MathOverflow, and it was refused.
